# Correlating %RDY in esxtop to CPU Usage in Guest

Tags: linux, vmware-esx

We recently upgrade a number of our VmWare hosts from 4.1 to 5.5 and noticed many of the VMs saw a step-wise jump in CPU usage as shown by the guest VM.  We have not yet upgraded vmwaretools on any of the guests, but after investigating a bit more we saw many of these guests with a high `%RDY` value (>50%) when viewed under `esxtop`.  Unfortunately Linux (the guest) just shows "high CPU usage" without any insight into what portion of that is coming from `%RDY` (VmWare saying, "your guest is waiting on CPU from the host").  Are there any tools, `/proc` entries, etc. that can shed light on that information?

Comment: Did you reboot/restart any guests? It would make sense to do so and also update VMware tools. 4.1 to 5.5 is a huge jump in functionality, VM guest hardware and tools capability.

Comment: No, the guests weren't restarted after the migration to 5.5.  I can try rebooting some of the guests and see if that makes a difference and also determine how easy it is to update to VmWare tools 5.5 (hopefully Ubuntu 10 guests can get upgraded to VmWare tools 5.5 without a lot of ... shall we say... "fanfare").  However, that still doesn't answer the basic question of how I can get visibility to `%RDY` inside my guests?

Answer (score 1):

You might get host information within your VM if you set `tools.guestlib.enableHostInfo=TRUE` in the advanced settings of your VMs. You might also have to set `Misc.GuestLibAllowHostInfo=TRUE` in the advanced settings of your hosts but I'm not sure about that.

I don't know if this works for Linux guests, too, as VMware talks explicitly about Windows:

> vSphere includes virtual machine performance counters on Windows
>   operating systems where VMware Tools is installed.

[Verify That Sending Host Performance Data to Guests is Disabled](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-2CF880DA-2435-4201-9AFB-A16A11951A2D.html)

This will probably not expose %RDY to the VM, at least it's not mentioned in [Security Considerations for Configuring VMware Tools](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-685722FA-9009-439C-9142-18A9E7C592EA.html).

I think there have been changes to the scheduler around 5.0 or 5.1. ESXi tries more aggressively to make use of data locality. If there are free cores the scheduler will not run a VM there if the VM's memory is in another NUMA node. Well, sooner or later it will but later than in 4.x which might be the cause for the higher %RDY times. (Sorry, but I don't have any reference for that.)

That said: Is this really a problem? You only talk about CPU usage (within the guest) and ready time (in the hypervisor) but you don't mention your application performance. Has it degraded with the upgrade, has it improved or is it just the same? If it hasn't degraded I wouldn't worry much about CPU usage / ready time.

Instead of trying to expose ready times and similar information to your guests you should investigate why your CPU ready times are high.